# How to get the each first row where the Product Id is in a comma separated string?

Tags: mysql

I have a string consisting of comma separated ids, e.g. Product Ids "1,2,3,46,15,...", being passed to a Stored Procedure. This string can have thousands of Ids.

I have a table 'Orders' with the Product Ids and there can be duplicates for the Product Ids.

I need the first occurrence of each ID from the above string ("1,2,3,46,15,...") from the Orders table.

| Order Id | Product Id | Order Date | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2012-01-01 | $12.25 |
| 2 | 1 | 2012-02-01 | $123.55 |
| 3 | 2 | 2012-03-01 | $12.25 |
| 4 | 3 | 2012-01-02 | $123.55 |
| 5 | 15 | 2012-01-02 | $12.25 |
| 6 | 3 | 2012-11-02 | $123.55 |
| 7 | 46 | 2012-01-03 | $12.25 |
| 8 | 1 | 2012-01-02 | $123.55 |
| 9 | 46 | 2012-01-01 | $12.25 |
| 10 | 3 | 2012-01-02 | $123.55 |
| 11 | 2 | 2012-01-01 | $12.25 |
| 12 | 3 | 2012-01-02 | $123.55 |
| ... |  |  |  |

Using the string, "1,2,3,46,15,...", should get:

| Order Id | Product Id | Order Date | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2012-01-01 | $12.25 |
| 3 | 2 | 2012-03-01 | $12.25 |
| 4 | 3 | 2012-01-02 | $123.55 |
| 5 | 15 | 2012-01-02 | $12.25 |
| 7 | 46 | 2012-01-03 | $12.25 |
| ... |  |  |  |

The Product Id doesn't have to be ordered.

Currently using Find_In_Set but performance is terrible for string with thousands of ids.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: "I need the first occurrence of each ID" -- Huh?  the id is either there or not; what do you mean by "first occurrence"?  The position in the list?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption you are using v8 you can take advantage of `json_table` to split the incoming string into rows which you can join to your `Orders` table;

Then `row_number` lends itself to selecting the first (based on `Order_Id`) of duplicate `Product_Id` values.

```
with p as (
  select o.*, row_number() over(partition by o.Product_Id order by o.order_id) rn
  from (select '1,2,3,46,15' Id ) s
  join json_table(
    replace(json_array(s.Id), ',', '","'),
    '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')
    ) j
  join Orders o on o.product_id = j.Id
)
select Order_Id, Product_Id, Order_Date, Total_Cost
from p
where rn = 1;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aef8cc37fe97dc05018888e6774b5608)